# Taking an array within a JSON file and exploding it into rows using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have some JSON that is in the following format:

```
{"items": ["234", "454", "434", "534"], "time": "1574290618029", "id": "A1", "user": "Bob"}
{"items": ["432", "123", "765"], "time": "1574200618021", "id": "B1", "user": "Tim"}
{"items": ["437"], "time": "1274600618121", "id": "B1", "user": "Joe"}
```

Each JSON is brought into a dataframe using

```
spark.read.json(path)
```

and looping through to union them all into a single dataframe.

```
df.show()
```

shows something like this:

```
|items| id| time| user|
|["234", "454", "434", "534"] | "1574290618029" | "A1" | "Bob"|
|["432", "123", "765"] | "1574200618021" | "B1" | "Tim"|
|["437"] | "1274600618121" | "B1" | "Joe"|
```

Doing a df.explode(df.id, df.time, df.user, explode(df.items)).show() results in something very close, but not quite what I'm looking for.

```
|id| time| user| col|
|A1| 1574290618029| Bob| 234|
|A1| 1574290618029| Bob| 454|
|A1| 1574290618029| Bob| 434|
|A1| 1574290618029| Bob| 534|
|B1| 1574200618021| Tim| 432|
|B1| 1574200618021| Tim| 123|
|B1| 1574200618021| Tim| 765|
|B1| 1274600618121| Joe| 437|
```

What I am actually needing is the data to be in a format like this:

```
|id| time| user| item_num| col|
|A1| 1574290618029| Bob| item1| 234|
|A1| 1574290618029| Bob| item2| 454|
|A1| 1574290618029| Bob| item3| 434|
|A1| 1574290618029| Bob| item4| 534|
|B1| 1574200618021| Tim| item1| 432|
|B1| 1574200618021| Tim| item2| 123|
|B1| 1574200618021| Tim| item3| 765|
|B1| 1574200618021| Tim| item4| NA|
|B1| 1274600618121| Joe| item1| 437|
|B1| 1274600618121| Joe| item2| NA|
|B1| 1274600618121| Joe| item3| NA|
|B1| 1274600618121| Joe| item4| NA|
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this utilizing explode that I'm not seeing? I'm also very new to spark coding so please excuse me if there is some very obvious answer...

Comment: Will the array always contains a maximum of 4 items?

Comment: No, the array does not have a specified maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive `explode` won't work in this case since you need to pad the array before exploding it to get the `NA` values.

To achieve this,

1. First we need to identify the maximum size of the array
2. Compute a [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sequence.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sequence) from 1 to maximum array size
3. [`array_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip) sequence with `items` to get a map with array index as key and value as item. This ensures that for array index where value is not present a `null` value is added to the map
4. Explode the `map` from step 4
5. Extract `item_num` and `col` for each row to get the desired output

## Working Example

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data = [{"items": ["234", "454", "434", "534"], "time": "1574290618029", "id": "A1", "user": "Bob"},
{"items": ["432", "123", "765"], "time": "1574200618021", "id": "B1", "user": "Tim"},
{"items": ["437"], "time": "1274600618121", "id": "B1", "user": "Joe"},
{ "items": [], "time": "1274600618121", "id": "C1", "user": "EmptyUser"},
{"items": None, "time": "1274600618121", "id": "D1", "user": "NullUser"},]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

max_number_of_items = df.selectExpr('max(size(items)) as max_items').take(1)[0].max_items

padded_array_df = df.withColumn("items", arrays_zip(sequence(lit(1), lit(max_number_of_items)).alias("index"), 
                                                    coalesce(col("items"), array([])).alias("items")))

padded_array_df.select("id", "time", "user", explode("items").alias("items"))\
               .select("id", "time", "user", concat(lit("item"), col("items").getField("index")).alias("item_num"), col("items").getField("items").alias("col"))\
               .show()
```

### Output

```
+---+-------------+---------+--------+----+
| id|         time|     user|item_num| col|
+---+-------------+---------+--------+----+
| A1|1574290618029|      Bob|   item1| 234|
| A1|1574290618029|      Bob|   item2| 454|
| A1|1574290618029|      Bob|   item3| 434|
| A1|1574290618029|      Bob|   item4| 534|
| B1|1574200618021|      Tim|   item1| 432|
| B1|1574200618021|      Tim|   item2| 123|
| B1|1574200618021|      Tim|   item3| 765|
| B1|1574200618021|      Tim|   item4|null|
| B1|1274600618121|      Joe|   item1| 437|
| B1|1274600618121|      Joe|   item2|null|
| B1|1274600618121|      Joe|   item3|null|
| B1|1274600618121|      Joe|   item4|null|
| C1|1274600618121|EmptyUser|   item1|null|
| C1|1274600618121|EmptyUser|   item2|null|
| C1|1274600618121|EmptyUser|   item3|null|
| C1|1274600618121|EmptyUser|   item4|null|
| D1|1274600618121| NullUser|   item1|null|
| D1|1274600618121| NullUser|   item2|null|
| D1|1274600618121| NullUser|   item3|null|
| D1|1274600618121| NullUser|   item4|null|
+---+-------------+---------+--------+----+
```

Comment: Not really sure why, but when I attempt at replicating your example, I keep getting "AnalysisException: 'No such field index in 0, items'"

Comment: I suspect you attempt to make the logic I had null-safe or empty array safe and that introduced a column naming mismatch. I have updated the answer for null and empty arrays. If the issue persists, will be needing debugging logs to support further.

Comment: Thank you! I think I figured it out. It was probably a combination of empty array handling as well as in this line: .select("id", "time", "user", concat(lit("item"), col("items").getField("index")).alias("item_num"), col("items").getField("items").alias("col")) - The .getField calls should be getItem calls instead right?

Comment: @paytur `arrays_zip` returns a struct and hence `getField` is used to access the contents of the `struct`